# How to display the latest news from a web news feed in delphi firemonkey application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Well, I have a program and a website, the website has to part with the latest news, only formatted with CSS3, etc. .. I have no idea how to display in my delphi program the latest news, since the TWebBrowser is not transparent, can not render CSS3 and HTML5, has some other way?

Answer (score 13):

Publish your news in an RSS feed. In your program, fetch that feed with something like Indy, extract the important parts with an XML parser, and present it however you want. You don't need to embed a Web browser for that.

You can rig your Web server to generate the news page using input from that same RSS feed.

Comment: +1. Well, actually, I agree, except that the guy seems to be in love with CSS3 and HTML5.  :-)

Answer (score 7):

Try [Delphi Chromium Embedded](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/). It has the same HTML5 and CSS features as Google Chrome, more or less. No adobe flash support out of box though.  I have not used it with Firemonkey yet, but there is a demo of doing that [here](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/trunk/demos/firemonkey/firemonkey.dproj?r=119).

Comment: What on earth do you mean by need a transparency?

Comment: The component must have a transparent background, because the program has a background ..

Comment: Do yourself a favour and make your program's background the background of the page you load in Chromium Embedded. I don't think you will be able to get any Web Browser type component to be transparent. After all, their nature is to render complete pages, including background (which probably defaults to white)...

Comment: As @MarjanVenema has said why change this? Surely this undermines the concept of a webbrowser / webpage doesn't it?

Comment: If the OP has a background in his program, he shouldn't be using a web browser control at all. He should go with Rob's idea.  IT's not that hard to show your news stuff using your own VCL or Firemonkey controls.

Comment: @Marjan, the `CefWindowInfo` class used in private `CreateBrowser` method should have the member `SetTransparentPainting` though, but one thing is that Delphi wrapper doesn't implement it and the other thing is that the version for Firemonkey has the `m_bWindowRenderingDisabled` option set to True what enables the owner drawing of the browser content (what gives you even more flexibility). Take a look at the `TCustomChromiumFMX.doOnPaint` and `TCustomChromiumFMX.Paint` in [`ceffmx.pas`](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/trunk/src/ceffmx.pas).