# How can I get flash working with Chromium?

Tags: delphi, chromium

I have installed Chromium for Delphi, but there does not appear to be out of the box flash support for it, as mentioned in this post:

[How to display the latest news from a web news feed in delphi firemonkey application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708186/how-to-display-the-latest-news-from-a-web-news-feed-in-delphi-firemonkey-applica)

How can one enable flash for Chromium?

Answer (score 0):

kind of old, for dcef1 you should google for gcswf32.dll. it's old chrome flash player plugin.
for dcef3 i think you need to have instaled flash on the system, no way to embedd dll but I might be wrong.